# Keep position in list with new items Flutter ListView

Tags: listview, flutter

I am building a Flutter app and have run into a problem with the ListView.builder.

My current setup is a StreamBuilder which has a list of objects. Each object is bound to 1 item in the ListView.builder.

My problem is that when new items are added and I called StreamController$add() the list is automatically scrolled to the top of the list. I am looking for the list position to be maintained and it is up to the user (or a button) to scroll to the top.

I have added keys to the list items which helped other issues but not this one. I also added a PageStorageKey to the listview but that did not help. I have a scroll controller also but have not been able to figure out how to work this behavior.

I can provide code samples if needed. Thanks in advance!

Relevant code:

```
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      theme: albatrossDarkTheme,
      home: TimelinePage(),
    );
  }
}

class TimelinePage extends StatefulWidget {
  TimelinePage({Key key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _TimelinePageState createState() => _TimelinePageState();
}

class _TimelinePageState extends State<TimelinePage> {
  AlbatrossClient _client;
  GlobalKey<ScaffoldState> _scaffoldKey = GlobalKey();
  PageStorageKey _pageKey = PageStorageKey(8);
  TimelineDatabase _database = TimelineDatabase();
  StreamController<List<Tweet>> _controller;
  ScrollController _scrollController;

  Stream<List<Tweet>> _getStream() {
    return _controller.stream;
  }

  Future<void> _refreshTimeline() async {
    _client.refreshTimeline().then((result) {
      if (result == 0)
        _database.getTimeline(false).then((update) {
          _controller.add(update);
        });
    });
  }

  _updateTimeline() async {
    _database.getTimeline(false).then((update) => _controller.add(update));
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    _client = AlbatrossClient();
    _controller = StreamController<List<Tweet>>();
    _scrollController = ScrollController(keepScrollOffset: true);
    _database.getTimeline(false).then((saved) => _controller.add(saved));
      _client.refreshTimeline().then((result) {
        if (result == 0)
          _database.getTimeline(false).then((update) {
            _controller.add(update);
          });
      });

    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _controller.close();
    _scrollController.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      key: _scaffoldKey,
      appBar: SearchAppbar(() {
        _scaffoldKey.currentState.openDrawer();
      }),
      drawer: Drawer(
        child: DrawerMain.getDrawer(context, _client.getProfile()),
      ),
      body: Container(
          child: RefreshIndicator(
              onRefresh: _refreshTimeline,
              child: StreamBuilder<List<Tweet>>(
                stream: _getStream(),
                builder: (context, snapshot) {
                  if (snapshot.hasData) {
                    return ListView.builder(
                      key: _pageKey,
                      controller: _scrollController,
                      itemCount:
                          snapshot.data != null ? snapshot.data.length : 0,
                      itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                        return RowTweet(
                            tweet: snapshot.data[index],
                            update: _updateTimeline,
                            animate: true);
                      },
                    );
                  } else
                    return Container(
                      alignment: Alignment(0.0, 0.0),
                      child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
                    );
                },
              ))),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        tooltip: 'Compose Tweet',
        onPressed: _composeTweet,
        foregroundColor: Colors.white,
        child: Image.asset(
          "icons/ic_tweet_web.webp",
          width: 38,
          height: 38,
        ),
      ), // This trailing comma makes auto-formatting nicer for build methods.
    );
  }
}
```

Here is my new attempt:

```
return Scaffold(
      key: _scaffoldKey,
      appBar: SearchAppbar(() {
        _scaffoldKey.currentState.openDrawer();
      }),
      drawer: Drawer(
        child: DrawerMain.getDrawer(context, _client.getProfile()),
      ),
      body: Container(
          child: RefreshIndicator(
              onRefresh: _refreshTimeline,
              child: _timeline.isNotEmpty
                  ? ListView.builder(
                      key: _pageKey,
                      controller: _scrollController,
                      itemCount: _timeline.length,
                      itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                        return RowTweet(
                            tweet: _timeline[index],
                            update: _updateTimeline,
                            animate: true);
                      })
                  : Container(
                      alignment: Alignment(0, 0),
                      child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
                    ))),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        tooltip: 'Compose Tweet',
        onPressed: _composeTweet,
        foregroundColor: Colors.white,
        child: Image.asset(
          "icons/ic_tweet_web.webp",
          width: 38,
          height: 38,
        ),
      ), // This trailing comma makes auto-formatting nicer for build methods.
    );
```

Answer (score 0):

So what's happening is that the entire list view is being rebuilt every time a new value is emitted through your stream. The way you solve this is to move the list view out of the stream builder and only modify the children of the list view in the stream builder.

I haven't used StreamBuilder extensively before so you'd have to figure it out in code. There's 2 ways this can be fixed.

1. Keep a list of widgets in a member variable, return your indicator if list it empty, otherwise return a ListView(_yourMemberListOfWidgets). Hook up to the stream without the stream builder. When a new value is returned set that to the list of widgets kept as a member variable and call setState to update your state.
2. Move your Stream builder into the ListView, compile and return the children only. If that's not possible then consider placing the StreamBuilder in a ScrollView and return a Column with all the children in there as widgets.  This will give the same effect. If you need touch input, just use GestureDetector around your list items and implement the onTap.

Comment: Seems that I need to add code as I am in fact using a stateful widget

Comment: Yep, having the code would help us figure out the problem.

Comment: @NickMowen changed the answer.

Comment: I added my second attempt at this which still did not work and moves to the top when adding new items. The thing that is interesting is that both with the stream builder and this new attempt, liking a tweet (which updates the database and the stream / list) does not move the list, but adding new items seems to push it to the top.

Comment: It seems that it doesn't necessarily scroll to the top, just that the list jumps by the height of the new items added. I am trying to disable this jump

Comment: @NickMowen yeah, jumping by the new height makes a bit more sense. Just add some manual code to save your position on newRequestMade and then when the request comes back call setState and set the position to that same position again.

Comment: The problem is that the ListView does not have a scroll to position method, only a scroll to offset which I can't calculate easily since my views are variable height

Comment: @NickMowen then I don't know what's happening. I would have to debug to check it out, but it seems that this stateful list would help. It keeps track of the offset, so you can expose that and add some custom handling for yourself. https://medium.com/@boldijar.paul/flutter-keeping-list-view-index-while-changing-page-view-c260352f35f8

Answer (score 0):

In your ListView.builder you have used a `key` attribute. you can try skipping that.